# Disable/hide text boxes based on radio button selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5xKW/1/)

**Is it possible** to disable and change the style of text boxes based on the radio button that has been selected?

For example I need "REF" and "Title" text boxes to be enabled only if "Project" has been selected, and "Name" if "Account" is selected.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td td1">
                <input type="radio" name="section1a" id="radio1-1" value="radio" />
                <label class="large black" for="radio1-1">Project</label>
            </div>
            <div class="td td2"> <span class="large black">Ref:</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="td td3">
                <input class="form-textbox" name="ref" type="text" placeholder="Insert project reference" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td td1"></div>
            <div class="td td2"> <span class="large black">Title:</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="td td3">
                <input class="form-textbox" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Insert project title" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td td1">
                <input type="radio" name="section1a" id="radio1-2" value="radio" />
                <label class="large black" for="radio1-2">Account</label>
            </div>
            <div class="td td2"> <span class="large black">Name:</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="td td3">
                <input class="form-textbox" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Insert account name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td td1">
                <input type="radio" name="section1a" id="radio1-3" value="radio" />
                <label class="large black" for="radio1-3">General Business</label>
            </div>
            <div class="td td2"></div>
            <div class="td td3">
                <input class="form-textbox" name="organization" type="text" placeholder="Insert client organisation name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So.. what have you tried to accomplish this?>

Comment: Stackoverflow is used to problem solution. Not for getting ready made code.

Comment: @putvande Well I found some code that looks like it is not very efficient. http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=48017

Comment: Why isn't it very efficient?

Comment: @antindexer If you read the question, you would see that I am asking if it is possible. I was looking for the method I need. Hence why I added the tags, CSS, Javascript and JQuery, which means I don't know which I need. I do not ask for ready made code.

Comment: @tymeJV because the "Disablefield" function fires twice when it is changed. In their case with just 2 options, it would be fine with checking if one has changed, but in my case with 3, I am unsure on the best way.

Comment: @Joey jquery is javascript library. Changing dynamically elements behaviour under some events can be done using only javascript or any other related library to javascript. So, which leads you want to get some ready made answer not suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use disabled to disable a control in javascript, add an event listener to your radio button and you're set, here is an exemple:

```
var rbProject = document.getElementById('radio1-1');

rbProject.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    txtRef.disabled = false;
    txtTitle.disabled = false;
    txtName.disabled = true;
})
```

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t5xKW/3/) show you how it's done !

Answer (score 1):

You could do this fairly easily with jQuery. Here's an example of how to change CSS of an element:

```
$(yourSelectorHere).css({ "font-weight": "bold",
        "color": "black"
});
```

And here is how to disable / re-enable an element:
Disable:

```
$(yourSelectorHere).attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Enable:

```
$(yourSelectorHere).removeAttr("disabled");
```

Hope this helps get you started. For reference, here are links to the jQuery API:
http://api.jquery.com/css/
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: This is great thanks. Some people thought I wanted someone to code it for me, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If you wouldn't mind marking this as the answer if it is what you seek it'd be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing you need to do is check which radio button is checked. Now, jQuery comes with a `.change()` method, which in your case could be used like:

```
$(":radio").change(function() {
```

Now, you don't have any `value` attribute that is useful associated with your radios, you should! (Then you can just check `this.value`, example: the radio with Project associated with it should have `value='project'` as an attribute).

So, now you would check which radio is selected:

```
var value = this.value; 
//if you dont have a value yet, I see you have labels with text
var value = $(this).next("label").text(); //although this way is ugly IMO
```

Now, check which one was selected!

```
if (value == "Project") {
    //A project radio is selected
    $(":text").prop("disabled", true); //this line is key, it disables all textboxes on change, now you enable the ones that you need
    //Enable boxes that match criteria
}
```

And thats the basics of it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though stackoverflow is not for creating complete lines of code, this is what you can use if you are familiar with jquery.

You can add CSS classes by using the addClass function.

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly the same scenario:

http://codepen.io/craig-wayne01/pen/LqeHl

```
<fieldset>
<input type=radio name=category><label>Project</label>
<label>Ref:</label><input type=text>
<label>Title:<label><input type=text>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<input type=radio name=category><label>Account</label><label>Name:</label><input type=text>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<input type=radio name=category><label>General Business</label><input type=text>
</fieldset>

<style>

fieldset{
border:none;
}

fieldset>label:first-of-type{
width:150px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}

fieldset>label:not(:first-of-type){
display:inline-block;
}

input[type=radio]:not(:checked)+label ~*{
opacity:0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label ~*{
opacity:1;
}
</style>
```